# Microsoft ADFS - Error loading Relying Party Trusts

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, adfs2.0

I have ADFS 2.0 installed on Windows Server 2008 R2. It was working fine all these days until I started encountering an issue when I select "Relying Party Trust". It says **"An error occurred during an attempt to access the ADFS configuration database: Error message ADMIN0017: An exception occurred while connecting to the configuration service. The configuration service URL may be incorrect or the ADFS 2.0 Windows Service is not running"**

Window Service is running. I tried restarting the service, but still the issue persists.

How do I resolve this issue, w/o having to reinstall ADFS.

Comment: Are you using the default WID (windows internal database) or an external SQL instance?